Time series projection problem, the stationarity is unnecessary here?
Problem
(Time-Methods-Peter-J-Brockwell problem 2.8):
Suppose $\{X_t,t=1,2,\cdots\}$ is a stationary process with mean zero. Show that
$$
P_{\bar{sp}\{1,X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}}X_{n+1}=P_{\bar{sp}\{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}}X_{n+1}
$$
My proof
By definition of projection, we know
$$
P_{\bar{sp}\{1,X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}}X_{n+1} \in \bar{sp}\{1,X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}
$$
thus we have some $\alpha_k, k=0,1,2,\cdots,n$ such that
$$
P_{\bar{sp}\{1,X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}}X_{n+1} = \alpha_0+\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k X_k
$$
By projection thm.
$$
X_{n+1} - \alpha_0 - \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k X_k \quad \perp \quad \bar{sp}\{1, X_1,X_2\cdots,X_n\}
$$
since $1\in \bar{sp}\{1, X_1,X_2\cdots,X_n\}$ then
$$
E(X_{n+1} - \alpha_0 -\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k X_k) = -\alpha_0 = 0
$$
Thus
$$
X_{n+1} - P_{\bar{sp}\{1,X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}}X_{n+1} =X_{n+1}-\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k X_k\quad \perp \quad \bar{sp}\{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}
$$
Apply projection thm on space $\bar{sp}\{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}$
$$
P_{\bar{sp}\{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}}X_{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n \beta_k X_k
$$
and, under condition of orthogonality
$$
X_{n+1} - \sum_{k=1}^n \beta_k X_k \quad \perp \quad \bar{sp}\{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}
$$
the projection is unique. Thus
$$
P_{\bar{sp}\{1,X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}}X_{n+1}=P_{\bar{sp}\{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}}X_{n+1}
$$
My question
The stationarity of $X_t$ is unnecessary here?

maybe my proof is wrong...
